# Creating Users from Arrays in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell

Hello I'm using Active Directory for a while now and I want to make a user creation script from arrays to learn how it works and yes I know I can make a CSV and import it and it works like magic I know all that but I want to use Powershell and New-ADUser and some arrays to make accounts like a loop

I made this code because I am too new in powershell my skills are very noobish

```
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Pa$$w0rd" -AsPlainText -Force
$name = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input username'
$OU = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input OU'
New-ADUser $name -AccountPassword $pwd -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False -PasswordNeverExpires $true -Path "OU=$OU,DC=contoso,DC=com"
Enable-ADAccount -Identity $name
```

what I wanted to know and I couldn't find a lot of info about it is how do I make arrays of OU's and Arrays of Usernames and OU's and make the command roll 5-10 times and the reason I want this is to learn more about powershell and see how it works and where I can go with it

EDIT: 
ok I played a little with powershell and foreach and ended up with this

```
$UserArray = ('Bi','Ba','Bo')
foreach ($user in $userArray) {
New-ADUser $user -SamAccountName $user -AccountPassword $pwd -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False -PasswordNeverExpires $true -Path "OU=labs,DC=contoso,DC=com"
Enable-ADAccount -Identity $user
}
```

now what about the OU and how do I make a command that lets me add things inside the Array like I start writing names then after I ended up adding all the names I want and what name goes into what OU it just runs this command

EDIT2: ok so after some work and examples I got to this
but for some reason it creates the user Testing in OU sales and I cant understand why

```
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Pa$$w0rd" -AsPlainText -Force
$a = @('Test1','Sales2','Labs3')
$b = @('Testing','Sales','Labs')
$values = $a,$b
$user = $values[0]
$ou = $values[1]

ForEach-Object {
New-ADUser $user -SamAccountName $user -AccountPassword $pwd -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False -PasswordNeverExpires $true -Path "OU=$ou,DC=contoso,DC=com"
Enable-ADAccount -Identity $user
}
```

and most of the time it gives me errors for -SamAccountName something about Strings

Comment: Voting to close because it seems a lot like you want a programming tutorial...

Comment: I'm making a project and in the project it says to make a script and instead of importing users from CSV I want to make it that way and learn on the way whats wrong with that?

Comment: Only that it's not on topic for stackoverflow. A good answer would be a programming tutorial, which is too big for a stack overflow answer. You've asked a lot of wide-ranging vague things, so there's no way to give an answer which can be accepted as "clearly answering a question".

Answer (score 1):

Use and array of arrays, or an array of hash sets.

Play around with code like this and incorporate into your project.

```
$newUsersInOU1 = @()
$newUsersInOU1 += "OU=labs,DC=contoso,DC=com", "Ba"
$newUsersInOU1 += "OU=office,DC=contoso,DC=com", "Bb"
$newUsersInOU1 += "OU=hq,DC=contoso,DC=com", "Bc"
$newUsersInOU1 += "OU=labs,DC=contoso,DC=com", "Bd"
$newUsersInOU1 | ft -AutoSize

## or 

$newUsersInOU2 = @()
$newUsersInOU2 += @{OU="OU=labs,DC=contoso,DC=com"; User="Ba"}
$newUsersInOU2 += @{OU="OU=office,DC=contoso,DC=com"; User="Bb"}
$newUsersInOU2 += @{OU="OU=hq,DC=contoso,DC=com"; User="Bc"}
$newUsersInOU2 += @{OU="OU=labs,DC=contoso,DC=com"; User="Bd"}
$newUsersInOU2 | ft -AutoSize

$newUsersInOU2[1].OU
$newUsersInOU2[1].User
```